# Saving data in a .db file - java.io.File

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

I'm trying to save the data of a JAVA program in a .db file but isn't working.
The following message error appears:

"`java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at server.server.main(server.java:27)
Running`"

My program is a Client-Server model working with JAVA RMI. I have 2 clients, 2 interfaces and then multiple classes including a server class and an implementation class with all the methods.

The "save" method is in the implementation class as follows:

```
    public void save() {
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("C:/Users/Myself/Desktop/Hospital.db")));
        out.writeObject(this);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

In the server class:

```
try {
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {               
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new java.io.File("C:/Users/Myself/Desktop/Hospital.db")));
            read = (implementation)in.readObject();
            in.close();
            System.out.println(read);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            read = new implementation();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            read = new implementation();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            read = new implementation();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The "save" method is then used in both clients.

Comment: as far as I can see you are _reading_ from file, not _writing_

Comment: i think before the client finishes writing the file, the server may be trying to read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception stack trace shows an enf of file while trying to *read* the object stream header. From this we can determine several things:

- the problems occurs while *reading* an object from file `C:/Users/Myself/Desktop/Hospital.db`. It does not happen while writing an object as your problem description seems to imply
- the trace `ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader()` shows that the stream is trying to read its header, so it happens at the beginning of the file. The stream header is normally made of 2 short values `AC ED` and `00 05`, the first 4 bytes in the stream
- the fact that EOFException is thrown before the stream header can be read implies that the stream has less than 4 bytes in it. I'll even bet it's empty. Why is it empty? It's impossible to know without seeing more of your code

So, in short: your code is trying to deserialize an object from an empty file, causing the exception you are observing.